# How can i modify getItemViewType() with adapter input as a string and cursor?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I have created a recycler view and want to put two lists in it.
The first list is just a string that gets changed into fonts, which I have implemented in the onBindView method.
The second list is the cursor which includes the favorite fonts of the users.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706654/14599955) answer on SO but I don't have any idea how I'm going to modify the getItemViewType() method so that I can get to know which list type is currently calling for view.

My adapter code
here data is the class that contains the list of fonts

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_TEXTVIEW = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_1 = 1;
    private int total_no_of_row;
    private Context context;
    private String str;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int total_no_of_row, String str , Cursor cursor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.total_no_of_row = total_no_of_row;
        this.str = str;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TEXTVIEW) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            return new Item1Holder(view);
        }
        else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_1){
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            return new Item2Holder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder instanceof Item1Holder){
            data d = new data();
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            Log.d("this2",cursor.getInt(1)+"");

            String temp = d.Convert(str, cursor.getInt(1));
            ((Item1Holder)holder).textView.setText(temp);
            ((Item1Holder)holder).rowNumber.setText("⚫");
            ((Item1Holder)holder).fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24);
        }else if(holder instanceof Item2Holder){
            data d = new data();
            String temp = d.Convert(str, position);
            ((Item2Holder)holder).textView.setText(temp);
            ((Item2Holder)holder).rowNumber.setText((position + 1) + ".");

            if (util.COPY) {
                if (position == util.CURRENT_POSITION) {
                    ((Item2Holder)holder).imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_when_row_clicked);
                } else {
                    ((Item2Holder)holder).imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_when_row_clicked_two);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return total_no_of_row + cursor.getCount();
    }

    class Item1Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView , fav;
        TextView rowNumber;

        public Item1Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_body);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copy_png);
            rowNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_number);
            fav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav);
        }
    }
    class Item2Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView , fav;
        TextView rowNumber;

        public Item2Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_body);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copy_png);
            rowNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_number);
            fav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav);
        }
    }


}
```

in main activity
here temp is the string that users want to convert into the fonts

```
Cursor cursor = show();
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this , 500 , temp , cursor);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

**I'm not a professional android developer I'm still learning the stuff. so sorry if my code is too bad to understand**

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method, and not specified position in `getItemViewType()` method. All you have to do is, update your code. do not pass the null value in the onCreateViewHolder method. Below code, I've tried, and works perfectly. Happy coding...

```
private static final int CATEGORY = 1;
private static final int NAME = 2;    

private Collection<CategorizedName> data;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
if (items.get(position) instanceof Category) {
    return CATEGORY;
} else if (items.get(position) instanceof Name) {
    return NAME;
}
throw new RuntimeException('error');
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

switch (viewType) {
    case CATEGORY:
        View categoryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewholder_category, viewGroup, 
    false);
        viewHolder = new CategoryViewHolder(categoryView);
        break;
    case NAME:
        View nameView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewholder_name, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new NameViewHolder(nameView);
        break;
  }
  return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
  switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
      case USER:
          CategoryViewHolder categoryViewHolder = (CategoryViewHolder) viewHolder;
          bindCategoryViewHolder(categoryViewHolder, position);
          break;
      case IMAGE:
          NameViewHolder nameViewHolder = (NameViewHolder) viewHolder;
          bindNameViewHolder(nameViewHolder, position);
          break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your getItemViewType() with this

```
  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        if(position < total_no_of_row){
            return VIEW_TYPE_TEXTVIEW;
        }
 
        if(position - total_no_of_row < cursor.getCount()){
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_1;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

you can also refer to my answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66587814/15377185)